# Alamofire post base 64 string error

Tags: ios, swift, base64, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire library to make a post request to post base 64 string.
when I post any data other than the base 64 string it successes, but when I try to post base 64 string it is posted successfully, but I did not get a response and the closure of Alamofire is never executed, after a while I got this exception:

> NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806)

Note : I have added the allow arbitrary loads and the sub-domain to info.plist with no result.

Comment: along if possible update question with code also so that have better idea about it.

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: the problem is not code related, i want to know how to solve the code resulting from this : NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9806